# Pandas Python Search JSON List

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file structured list so:

```
[
 {
   "name": "first",
   "points": 0.5,
   "tags": [{
      "key": "Owner",
      "value": "A"
   }]
 },
 {
   "name": "first",
   "points": 1.5,
   "tags": [{
      "key": "Owner",
      "value": "B"
   }]
 },
 {
   "name": "first",
   "points": 24,
   "tags": [{
      "key": "SomeOtherTag",
      "value": "XYZ"
   }]
 }
]
```

I want to load this JSON array then filter for a particular `key: value` tag and count the `points`. For example, filter this "master" list by `Owner: A` then count the points which should give me a result of `0.5`

I know how to calculate the points with `items.points.sum()` but I'm struggling to filter by the tag key / value.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

items = pd.read_json('all_items.json')

# Do something to filter down the list
filtered_items = ?????

print(filtered_items.points.sum())
```

Edit based on Rob's solution:

```
#pipenv install pandas
# pandas = 1.1.0

import pandas as pd

items = pd.read_json('all_items.json')

pd.json_normalize(items, record_path="tags", meta=[['name'], ['points']])
```

Gives `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(s)
print(df)

    name  points                                       tags
0  first     0.5           [{'key': 'Owner', 'value': 'A'}]
1  first     1.5           [{'key': 'Owner', 'value': 'B'}]
2  first    24.0  [{'key': 'SomeOtherTag', 'value': 'XYZ'}]

# to filter
filter_mask = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['value'] == 'A')
df.loc[filter_mask, "points"].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_normalize()` does it all for you

```
js = [{'name': 'first', 'points': 0.5, 'tags': [{'key': 'Owner', 'value': 'A'}]},
 {'name': 'first', 'points': 1.5, 'tags': [{'key': 'Owner', 'value': 'B'}]},
 {'name': 'first',
  'points': 24,
  'tags': [{'key': 'SomeOtherTag', 'value': 'XYZ'}]}]


pd.json_normalize(js, record_path="tags", meta=[['name'], ['points']])
```

**output**

```
          key value   name points
        Owner     A  first    0.5
        Owner     B  first    1.5
 SomeOtherTag   XYZ  first     24
```

### suplemenatary update

if reading from file

```
import json
with open('all_items.json') as f: items = json.load(f)

pd.json_normalize(items, record_path="tags", meta=[['name'], ['points']])
```

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: 1.1.0 - have used this capability since 0.2.x

Comment: capability did change with 1.0 - I have code that picks up version and uses parameters differently based on version

Comment: Thanks Rob, I've updated original post with my findings. I get a TypeError

Comment: I've updated answer,  you should just read the JSON as normal first before passing it through `json_normalize()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not rigid on using Pandas, an alternative would be to sum a generator comprehension, with the assumption that there is only one dictionary embedded in the `tags` list per row :

```
sum(entry["points"] for entry in data if entry["tags"][0]["value"] == "A")

0.5
```